# Angular router.navigate use array as list of queryParams

Tags: angular, query-string

Im navigating after building up a queryParams object with a form:

```
options {
    ...
    words: (4) ["chuck", "norris", "vs", "keanu", "reeves"]
}
```

Then `navigate` with that object to update the URL's parameters:

```
this.router.navigate(['/search'], { queryParams: options });
```

The URL `words` param is duplicated for each entry like this:

```
/search?words=chuck&words=norris&words=vs&words=keanu&words=reeves
```

How do we **pass in an array** to `queryParams` properly?

Links:
[angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate)
[alligator.io/angular/query-parameters](https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/)

queryParamsHandling has no affect on this.
Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/queryparam-with-array) repro.

Comment: One trick is to JSON stringify the data you are passing and retrieve it using JSON.parse

Comment: Whats wrong with duplication of  `words`? It could work like this :)

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure :
"While there is no definitive standard, most web frameworks allow multiple values to be associated with a single field (e.g. field1=value1&field1=value2&field2=value3)."

Another benefit is that you will automatically have an array of the query parameters inside the angular router state. So you don't have to manually parse the querystring.

Comment: I personally have never seen a URL with the same param multiple times, one for each value.

Comment: What does the `(4)` before the array of words add to the code? I have never come across this syntax in Typescript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're doing it the correct way, just use [params.getAll](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap#getAll) in your `/search` component:

```js
words: string[];

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => this.words = params.getAll('words'));
}
```

---

Update: working example on stackblitz: [angular-query-params-pass-array](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-query-params-pass-array?file=src/app/app-search.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks @Gais Zaher, but I'm not trying to get a param. I'm trying to set the params after building up an object to set.

Comment: @BenRacicot so the problem is that the `words` param is being duplicated? If so, I don't think it's a problem, this is the correct way to pass arrays in query parameters.