# What is the best way to store query paramaters in the URL dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, optional-parameters

I have multiple search fields and I want to store the query parameters in the URL but I am not sure how to do it.

The path of the component looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'detailedview/:type/:id', component: DetailViewComponent}
];
```

`:type` and `:id` are fixed values. After those values, I need to append such an url segment
`q=...&title=...&...` which length varies regarding which field one has filled. 
Then I need to fetch somehow the data.

Do you think I should add the following to my path:

```
{path: 'detailedview/:type/:id/:queryParams', component: DetailViewComponent}
```

and then get the whole segment and iterate through that segment or so:

```
this.queryParams = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('queryParams');
// assign the values from this.queryParams to other variables
```

or how should one do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1: Send as optional parameters

Route config

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'detailedview/:type/:id', component: DetailViewComponent}
];
```

Navigation source

```js
navigateToPath() {
  const optionalParams = {
    title: 'Sample',
    q: 'Sample',
    ...
  }
  this._router.navigate(['/detailedview', 'sampleType', 1, {optionalParams: JSON.stringify(optionalParams)}]);
}
```

Navigation recipient

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class DetailViewComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _actRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.optionalParams = JSON.parse(this._actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('optionalParams'));
  }
}
```

Resulting URL

```
/detailedview/sampleType/1;optionalParams=<Object>
```

#### Option 2: Send as query parameters

Route config

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'detailedview/:type/:id', component: DetailViewComponent}
];
```

Navigation source

```js
navigateToPath() {
  const params = {
    title: 'Sample',
    q: 'Sample',
    ...
  }
  this._router.navigate(['/detailedview', 'sampleType', 1], {queryParams: params});
}
```

Navigation recipient

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class DetailViewComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _actRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.type = this._actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('type');
    this.title = this._actRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('title'));
    this.q = this._actRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('q'));
  }
}
```

Resulting URL

```
/detailedview/sampleType/1?title=Sample&q=Sample
```

Answer (score 1):

well, you almost answered it yourself. the only thing is that you don't need to declare that you are using query params in the router.
example for retrieving title from query params:

```
title= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('title');
```

you can read more in [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments)

Comment: I know what you mean, but in my case ```:queryParams```should hold more than only one value. It can be that ```queryParams``` is ```title=Hello&q=Johann...```but it also can be only one value: ```q=Johan``` so without title. Do you understand what I mean? I would need all the values existing in this segment and assign it to the correct variable.

Comment: you can use   this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => this.words = params.getAll('words'));
 read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063455/angular-router-navigate-use-array-as-list-of-queryparams