# How to pass an object array value to queryParams

Tags: angular

Is there a way to do url in Angular?

```
http://www.example.com/?id=[1,2,3]&other=[4,5,6];
```

I created an object has object values.

```
let obj = {
    id:[1,2,3],
    other:[],
    someValues:null
}

this.router.navigate([], {queryParams: {id: obj.id}, relativeTo: this.route});
```

After redirect url converted to
[image]

How can I solve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063455/angular-router-navigate-use-array-as-list-of-queryparams

Comment: it is not solution. I want such as http://www.example.com/?id=[1,2,3]&other=[4,5,6];

Comment: I used same after redirected to ?id=1&id=2&id=3 its not an array

Answer (score 3):

I think that your format: [http://www.example.com/?id=[1,2,3]&other=[4,5,6]](http://www.example.com/?id=%5B1,2,3%5D&other=%5B4,5,6%5D) is not the best way to pass arrays as query params.

The [RFC6570 - URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) defines how to do it, and in your case, correct way could be: http://www.example.com/?id=1,2,3&other=4,5,6

So consider refactor your code to adopt this more commonly used pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will change my structure as you said.

Comment: I'am glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an array to the queryParams, angular will [serialize it](https://github.dev/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/router/src/create_url_tree.ts#L186) for you. This works for simple string arrays, but not for a complex array of objects.

For instance:

A queryParams like `{id:[1,2,3]}` will be parsed into `?id=1&id=2&id=3`

A queryParams like `{id:{key:"value"}}` will be parsed into `?id=[object Object]` (which is unusable)

If you want to pass an array or any JSON like data, I recommend using [jsonurl](https://jsonurl.org/) to serialize the `queryParams` to the url and parse them later. This is way cleaner/safer than using `JSON.serialize` / `JSON.parse`

And if, like I, you would like angular to allow storing objects into urls with a minimum of effort, please consider [voting up this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/47307)